# Apache Web Server is accessed from LAN but website (virtual host) not accessible from LAN

Tags: apache2

When I try to Apache web address (192.168.0.21) from LAN computers, it is accessed successfully.

I have created one website 10000MT in Apache web server and written below code in etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/10000MT.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/10000MT"
    ServerName 10000MT
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to access this website using 192.168.0.21/10000MT, it is giving below error message.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /10000MT was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.0.21 Port 80
```

Please let me know what changes I need to do to access this website from LAN computers. But I can access site without any issue from linux pc but not from other pcs from LAN.

EDIT:

etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/10000MT.conf - This file contains following mentioned code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/10000MT"
    ServerName 10000MT
</VirtualHost>
```

etc/apache2/sites-enabled/10000MT.conf - This file contains following mentioned code.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "var/www/10000MT"
    ServerName 10000MT
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You need to access you server like this `http://10000MT/`. If you get DNS error then add this to your hosts file `192.168.0.21 10000MT`.

Comment: I already added above line my hosts file. And when I am trying to access site like you suggested above, it is still giving 'not found' error...

Comment: you didn't mention it but did you link the 10000MT file to the sites-enabled folder? then restart apache2

Comment: As a follow-up to @JohnOrion's comment, you can link it by running `sudo a2ensite 10000MT`.

Comment: Yes, it is linked... I have updated my initial question with this info...

Comment: is this a typo? _etc/apache2/sites-avaiable/10000MT.conf_

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `192.168.0.21/10000MT` in a web browser, you don't need to create a virtual host for that. Just move `10000MT` folder inside `/var/www/html`. See default document root in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf`.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer until today when I read this again. Ty for this. But then why virtual host are so much important and how can it be used? Can you please provide some reference or brief explaination? Ty again...